# Confused about Thrift, what does it really do?

Tags: ruby, scala, cross-platform, thrift

Can someone explain to me what thrift really does?

Say i have a Rails app, and I also have some code written in Scala.

Could thrift be used to generate an interface for my Scala code so that I could call it from Ruby?

Would the Scala code have to be written as a daemon for this to work?

I'm not really sure what Thrift's job is, other than it is used to link between various languages.  Does it communicate over a socket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thrift is simply a binary serialization protocol. It is cross-language, so you can serialize in Scala, and then unserialize in Ruby.

Then you have to move the data, that's another story. You can use files, play directly with sockets, use a server, etc.

Comment: So how is this used for cross-platform development? Still not getting it!

Comment: 1) You write once the message/specification description. 2) You use the API of each one your language. 3) Profit. For more info, read: http://diwakergupta.github.com/thrift-missing-guide/

Comment: It's just a way to transfer data (like XML or JSON). To facilitate cross-platform development you have to build services that use it, using HTTP or some other protocol.

Comment: @Rafe No, you don't need to build services that use it using a specific protocol. Thrift also provides the service as well as the transport layer. You just write the implementation of your thrift interface.

Answer (score 0):

> So how is this used for cross-platform development? Still not getting it!

Your Ruby and Scala code can reside on different machines running completely different OSes.